# Application published in Xenapp 6 is not working as expected

Tags: xenapp

We hosted a application from Xenapp farm which is working good in some geographical locations.
However there were issue observed like below in some different geographical locations.

- Taking too much time while application getting opened.
- Frequent dis-connections while app is running.

There Xenapp farm is being accessed same across all location in Enterprise network. However this peculiar behavior is annoying the people accessing application.

Could you please share what can be cause and troubleshooting approach where i can trace the root cause?